# Matching incompletely qualified paths

Tags: python, python-2.7

Let's say I have a series of incompletely qualified paths, which are missing some parts, but are guaranteed to have two properties:

1. The final part of both the incompletely and the fully qualified paths will be exactly equal, and
2. The order of each part of the incompletely qualified path will match the actual order of the parts of the fully qualified path.

For example,

```
p1 = '/foo/baz/myfile.txt'
p2 = '/bar/foo/myfile.txt'
actual = '/foo/bar/baz/myfile.txt'
```

In this case, `p1` will match, but `p2` will not, because in the actual path, `bar` occurs after `foo`. Easy enough: `[actual.split('/').index(part) for part in p1.split('/')]` will be an ordered list, but the same comprehension but for `p2` will not.

But what happens if there are repetitions in the path?

```
p1 = '/foo/bar/bar/myfile.txt'
p2 = '/bar/bar/baz/myfile.txt'
actual = '/foo/bar/baz/bar/myfile.txt'
```

How can I identify that `p1` does match, but `p2` does not (because, although `baz` occurs after the first `bar`, it does not occur after the second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def match(path, actual):
    path = path.strip('/').split('/')
    actual = iter(actual.strip('/').split('/'))
    for pathitem in path:
        for item in actual:
            if pathitem == item:
                break
        else:
            # The for-loop never breaked, so pathitem was never found
            return False
    return True

q1 = '/foo/baz/myfile.txt'
q2 = '/bar/foo/myfile.txt'
p1 = '/foo/bar/bar/myfile.txt'
p2 = '/bar/bar/baz/myfile.txt'
actual = '/foo/bar/baz/bar/myfile.txt'

print(match(q1, actual))
# True

print(match(q2, actual))
# False

print(match(p1, actual))
# True

print(match(p2, actual))
# False
```

Comment: I found this approach simple. I had to reappropriate it for my purposes (iterating over large sets of candidate `actual`s) but it worked.

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1:** Using `list.index`:

```
def match(strs, actual):
    seen = {}
    act = actual.split('/')
    for x in strs.split('/'):
        if x in seen:
            #if the item was already seen, so start search 
            #after the previous matched index
            ind = act.index(x, seen[x]+1)
            yield ind
            seen[x] = ind
        else:
            ind = act.index(x)
            yield ind
            seen[x] = ind
...             
>>> p1 = '/foo/baz/myfile.txt'
>>> p2 = '/bar/foo/myfile.txt'
>>> actual = '/foo/bar/baz/myfile.txt'
>>> list(match(p1, actual))     #ordered list, so matched
[0, 1, 3, 4]
>>> list(match(p2, actual))     #unordered list, not matched
[0, 2, 1, 4]

>>> p1 = '/foo/bar/bar/myfile.txt'
>>> p2 = '/bar/bar/baz/myfile.txt'
>>> actual = '/foo/bar/baz/bar/myfile.txt'
>>> list(match(p1, actual))     #ordered list, so matched
[0, 1, 2, 4, 5]
>>> list(match(p2, actual))     #unordered list, not matched
[0, 2, 4, 3, 5]
```

---

**Method 2:** Using `defaultdict` and `deque`:

```
from collections import defaultdict, deque
def match(strs, actual):
    indexes_act = defaultdict(deque)
    for i, k in enumerate(actual.split('/')):
        indexes_act[k].append(i)
    prev = float('-inf')
    for item in strs.split('/'):
        ind = indexes_act[item][0]
        indexes_act[item].popleft()
        if ind > prev:
            yield ind
        else:
            raise ValueError("Invalid string")
        prev = ind
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> p1 = '/foo/baz/myfile.txt'
>>> p2 = '/bar/foo/myfile.txt'
>>> actual = '/foo/bar/baz/myfile.txt'
>>> list(match(p1, actual))
[0, 1, 3, 4]
>>> list(match(p2, actual))
    ...
    raise ValueError("Invalid string")
ValueError: Invalid string

>>> p1 = '/foo/bar/bar/myfile.txt'
>>> p2 = '/bar/bar/baz/myfile.txt'
>>> actual = '/foo/bar/baz/bar/myfile.txt'
>>> list(match(p1, actual))
[0, 1, 2, 4, 5]
>>> list(match(p2, actual))
    ...
    raise ValueError("Invalid string")
ValueError: Invalid string
```

Comment: Thanks: I wasn't aware I could pass an offset to `.index()`.